# How to track multiple open source projects inside of a single project with git?

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, git-remote, intro.js

I was wondering how to track multiple smaller/compartmentalized opensource projects in git that are included in a larger (code base size - not necessarily popularity wise) project.  Example:

Say I'd like to use the two open source projects inside an E-Commerce site I'm building:

- Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html)
- intro.js (http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

My file structure would look like this:

```
myrepo/front_end/style/bootstrap/
                    ├── css/
                    │   ├── bootstrap.css
                    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
                    ├── js/
                    │   ├── bootstrap.js
                    │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
                    └── img/
                        ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
                        └── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
myrepo/front_end/javascript/intro/
                    ├── intro.js
```

Since the two open source projects are small subsections of the project, if I were to set up remote repos for the two github project repos and then have local branches tracking the remote masters the local branches wouldn't resemble the project repo at all.

So, how do I track remote projects to make sure I incorporate bug fixes as soon as they are released?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

DS-MATT

Comment: Have a look at [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: And at [git subtree](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) as well. It might be easier, as you intend to update the subprojects often.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and added in my first git submodule.  Works well!  Thannk you James Allardice.

I'm using Sourcetree app for managing Git and I couldn't add a subtree, just a submodule.

The only problem, the submodule doesn't show me with tracking if there is any new commits on the upstream project, I just have to check those repos every time I start working in Sourcetree app.

Comment: This behavior is by design. It allows you to control when updates are pulled to your submodules, rather than getting potentially unstable or incompatible versions. It also means you can go back and view old versions of your project, complete with matching versions of the submodules they used.